# Making QRCode ActiveX Control for MS Access: Control Source Property

Tags: vba, ms-access, vb6, activex, qr-code

I wanted to implement a QR Code to Access2010 and I found https://github.com/yas78/QRCodeLibVBA. Referencing XLAM from Access did not work and I didn't want to insert all modules directly to Access as it makes the project messy.
So I decided to create an OCX file using ancient VB6 as it seemed to be the easiest way to encapsulate all the bits together into one simple object.

Finally, I have made an OCX that has several key properties: `DataString` which is the string to be displayed, `ByteModeCharsetName`, `ErrorCorrectionLevel`, `ForeRGB` and `BackRGB`, there are also methods `Refresh`, `Cls` and events `OnClick` and `OnDblClick`

It works fine in VB6 apps + Excel sheets + Excel forms but it behaves weird in Access forms, reports, etc.

Everything looks as one would expect in Excel:
[image: Excel printscreen]

This is how it looks in Access:
[image: MS Access printscreen]

- The custom properties are visible on the tab "Other" but they are not offered in VBA editor at all! However it does compile when entered manually.
- Resizing control behaves weird
- Control's Events like `OnClick` are not displayed at tab Event of Property Sheet

Here are my questions:

1. Are the Controls for Access "different" than for other office apps?
2. Why the hell are the properties hidden in editor?
3. How to "move" some properties to other tabs (categories), for example `ForeRGB` to tab Format (as usual for TextBoxes etc.)?
4. How to create `ControlSource` propety (on the DATA tab) which could be directly bound to a recordset without having to use a VBA? This way, I hope, I could use the control on the continuous forms as well. In fact, this is most important question.
5. Some tips for resizing? (not important)

I think I'm pretty close to my goal but I'm stuck at this point. I know the VB6 is obsolete but after reading [Creating Custom Controls for ms access 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011901/creating-custom-controls-for-ms-access-2010) VB6 seems to be easy choice. Any alternatives for writing OCX?

EDIT: **Final working control is available here** https://github.com/Combinatix/QRCodeAX

Comment: If interested, here is an [alternative](https://github.com/krishKM/Modern-UI-Components-for-VBA/blob/master/README.md#barcode-control-for-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 4. try setting your control's [`DataBindingBehavior` to `vbSimpleBound`](https://www.freetutes.com/learn-vb6-advanced/lesson13/p30.html) so that a scalar property (`ControlSource` in your case) can be bound via `DataSource` and `DataMember` properties.

For 3. use `Tools->Procedure Attributes...` menu, select `ControlSource` in Name, expand `Advanced>>` and select **Data** in `Property Category` combobox. You can do the same through **Object Browser (F2)**. Find your control, right click your property/method (should be **bold**) and choose `Properties...` context menu option. This works with methods and is more versatile than `Tools->Procedure Attributes...` approach.

Comment: I have briefly tested your advices and binded my `DataString` to the `Control Source`. It wors great! But the bastard Access now refuses to display the form as Continuous: _A form with a bound ActiveX control or an embedded object bound to a data source can't have its DefaultView property set to Continuous Forms._  I have a bad feeling about this... Any sugestions?

Comment: @Combinatrix As shared in my answer, generally, it's hard to impossible to make an ActiveX control display something else for every row. Bound ActiveX controls aren't available on continuous subforms. However, you can try using the `Detail_Paint` event to display something specific to the record being painted, but anything you do in `Detail_Paint` that triggers a repaint causes an infinite loop (and things that change how objects are displayed often trigger a repaint of the entire form).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions one by one:

1. Yes. ActiveX controls in Access are certainly different than in other Office applications.

   In Access, there's one general *CustomControl* control that encapsulates all ActiveX controls, and offers a default set of events, properties and methods for any control, such as border properties, the requery method, and the enter event.

   The object of the control being encapsulated can be accessed by using the `CustomControl.Object` proprty
2. These properties aren't displayed because you're referring to a custom control in the general sense, and only get the properties for it.

   To get the object you want, use the following:

   ```
   Dim qrObj As QRCode
   Set qrObj = QR.Object
   ```
3. That's plain not possible, tab layout is determined by Access
4. Also not possible. The ActiveX control must include that functionality, this one doesn't. Generally, using ActiveX controls in continuous subforms to display something different for every row is hard to impossible
5. Resizing the outer control, and then calling `CustomControl.SizeToFit` should generally just work

Some of the things I deem *not possible* can be achieved by modifying the ActiveX Control's source code, of course.

Comment: Rrright... Are you saying that  Access's `CustomControl` wrapper have to understand my OCX's props and then it can propagate them to the right property tabs? I have the source code and I can do what I want with it (almost)

Comment: Yup, wqw just shared an answer on that

Answer (score 0):

A very different and much less cumbersome approach would be to generate the QR code online and download them to be displayed in a (bound) picture control.

I wrote an article on displaying online images:

[Show pictures directly from URLs in Access forms and reports](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29679/Show-pictures-directly-from-URLs-in-Access-forms-and-reports.html?preview=1ydHj8EjNX8%3D)

Some code is, of course, needed, but much less than that at GiHub you refer to, though to much to list here in full.

It uses this function retrieve the images:

```
' Download (picture) file from a URL of a hyperlink field to a
' (temporary) folder, and return the full path to the downloaded file.
'
' This can be used as the control source for a bound picture control.
' If no Folder is specified, the user's IE cache folder is used.
'
' Typical usage in the RecordSource for a form or report where Id is
' the unique ID and Url is the hyperlink field holding the URL to
' the picture file to be displayed:
'
'   - to a cached file where parameter Id is not used:
'
'   Select *, UrlContent(0, [Url]) As Path From SomeTable;
'
'   - or, where Id is used to create the local file name:
'
'   Select *, UrlContent([Id], [Url], "d:\somefolder") As Path From SomeTable;
'
' Then, set ControlSource of the bound picture control to: Path
'
' 2017-05-28. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function UrlContent( _
    ByVal Id As Long, _
    ByVal Url As String, _
    Optional ByVal Folder As String) _
    As Variant

    Const NoError   As Long = 0
    Const Dot       As String = "."
    Const BackSlash As String = "\"
    
    Dim Address     As String
    Dim Ext         As String
    Dim Path        As String
    Dim Result      As String
    
    ' Strip leading and trailing octothorpes from URL string.
    Address = HyperlinkPart(Url, acAddress)
    ' If Address is a zero-length string, Url was not wrapped in octothorpes.
    If Address = "" Then
        ' Use Url as is.
        Address = Url
    End If
    
    If Folder = "" Then
        ' Import to IE cache.
        Result = DownloadCacheFile(Address)
    Else
        If Right(Folder, 1) <> BackSlash Then
            ' Append a backslash.
            Folder = Folder & BackSlash
        End If
    
        ' Retrieve extension of file name.
        Ext = StrReverse(Split(StrReverse(Address), Dot)(0))
        ' Build full path for downloaded file.
        Path = Folder & CStr(Id) & Dot & Ext
        
        If DownloadFile(Address, Path) = NoError Then
            Result = Path
        End If
    End If
    
    UrlContent = Result
    
End Function
```

I pasted this URL into a record:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=23457
```

and it worked right away:

[image: Sample]

Full code can be found at GitHub: [VBA.PictureUrl](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl.git)

Comment: I have used your Scenario 1 - Download and Display in the past. However this does not really answer my questions. My current OCX works almost perfect and after placing it to new access database it requires only one line of VBA `QR.DataString = Me!SomeField`. Also, the database stays internet-independend. The goal of my question was to find out how to insert Access-specific features into an OCX.

Comment: I've only worked with third-party OCX and don't have VB6, so I have no clue, sorry. Just wanted to make sure, you were aware of an alternative. Also, the use of OCX has decreased as they usually don't work with 64-bit Access.